# In how many ways can they sit so that no 2 men are sitting next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

There 14 women and 8 men and they want to sit on a circular table. In how many ways can they sit so that no 2 men are sitting next to each other?

There are $(14-1)!=13!$ ways in which women can sit.

Then there are $\binom{14}{8}$ so that men can sit, or not?

So do we get the answer by multiplying these two ?

Comment: I think derangement will work here. You keep subtracting no. of ways in which 2,3,4.... men can sit together.

Answer (score 2):

First of all select position for men.
Men can sit in $\binom{14}{8}$ position .

[image: Red one are position for women and green are AVALIABLE position for men]
Then both women and men can permute in $(14-1)!$ and $(8)!$ ways respectively.

Final answer=$$\binom{14}{8} \times 13! \times 8!$$

Comment: Ah ok! But this result is not at one of the choices. Is there maybe a typo?

Comment: may be .I think my solution is correct!!

Comment: @MaryStar: i had made a mistake there ..check my answer now!

Comment: I understand how you get that result! The possible result are $$ a) \frac{14!\cdot 15!}{7!} \ \ \ \ \ b) \frac{13!\cdot 14!}{6!} \ \ \ \ \ c) 22!-8! \ \ \ \ \ d) 14!\cdot 8!$$ So, your result is not equivalent of one of these, is it?

Comment: well by seeing the option ,none of them are matching.May be after solving $\binom{14}{8} \times 13! \times 7! $ , i may get any on them.

Comment: It also given that men and women are discrete. That doesn't change anything, does it? I got stuck right now.. Do you mean that the last $7!$ at your answer must be $8!$ ?

Comment: that was a typo

Comment: Because the other answer was deleted (so is invisible for you now) I will repeat my answer on your request here: @laura I feel flattered, but in principle: "no". This to avoid pressure on myself (I dislike it). This "no" however does not exclude that I will check your answer, but if this happens then not because I promised, but purely because I choose to do that. I have no doubt that you will understand that :-).

Comment: I think you did not take into account that men are not allowed to sit next to men. Further I suspect that persons are distinguishable here.

Comment: Ah when we take that into account, what do we have to change? @drhab

Comment: This is not quite right.  Seat a particular woman.  Let's call her Mary in honor of the OP.  Once she is seated, there are $13!$ ways to seat the remaining women as we proceed clockwise around the table relative to Mary.  The positions of the men can be selected in $\binom{14}{8}$ ways.  However, the number of ways the men can be seated in those positions is $8!$ since we must seat them relative to Mary.

Comment: So, you mean that there are $\binom{14}{8}\cdot 8!\cdot 13!$ ways, right? @N.F.Taussig

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that is correct.  If you simplify that expression, you will see that it corresponds to one of the given answers.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that the persons are distinguisable and the seats are not.

Place one of the men at the table. Starting at his left hand there comes a sequence of the form:$$.m.m.m.m.m.m.m.$$where every dot stands for at least one woman and every  $m$ for one man.

This comes to finding the number of sums $w_1+\cdots+w_8=14$ where the $w_i$ are positive integers, or equivalently to finding the number of sums $v_1+\cdots+v_8=6$ where the $v_i$ are nonnegative integers.

Without distinghuishing persons and applying [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we find that this can be achieved on $\binom{13}7$ ways. There are $7!$ orders for men and $14!$ for women, so the final answer is:$$\binom{13}77!14!=\frac{13!14!}{6!}$$If also seats are distinguisable then this must be multiplied with factor $22$ corresponding with the number of seats available for the man that was placed at the table as first.